# Magento 2.2.7 - How to change order total value only for payment?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I'm using installment payment method. So, I need to reduce my 
order total to send payment only....

I cannot find how Magento managing the order total and provide to 
third party payment providers.

Can some one provide any suggestions to change this

Comment: Magento does not send provide order detail to payment providers itself. Payment providers build their code  in the way so that they can get current checkout session or quote id  on redirection to  payment provider page.

Comment: @AmitBera Is it possible to set custom grandtotal (or)  price without saving in quote table on place order?